# Add a field to all the contenttypes of the current list

Tags: list, content-type

I have two content types that I want to use to more than one list.

I want to add a Field to ONLY one of those lists, but I want to add the field to both the content types of the list, without modifind the content types.
If i only add the field to the list with the Lists.Create() method , the filed is added only to the first oh the content types.

I can use the 
FieldLink.Add() method but it will propagate the change also to the other lists.

Here is my code: it works for my list but it also propagate the change of the CT to the other lists.

```
SPList list = Lists.Create(web, Constants.LIST_NAME_TOPCLICKED, Constants.CT_ID_ARTICOLO_IMM);

if (list != null)

{  

list.ContentTypes.Add(web.ContentTypes[new SPContentTypeId(Constants.CT_ID_ARTICOLO_VID)]);

list.Update();               

list.Fields.Add(Constants.AF_VISUALIZZA, SPFieldType.Boolean, true);

SPField fld = list.Fields.GetField(Constants.AF_VISUALIZZA);             

SPFieldLink fl = new SPFieldLink(fld);         

SPContentType ct = list.ContentTypes[Constants.CT_AV];

ct.FieldLinks.Add(fl);           

ct.Update();              

ct = list.ContentTypes[Constants.CT_AI];

ct.FieldLinks.Add(fl);               

ct.Update();

list.Update();

}
```

the field name is Constants.AF_VISUALIZZA
the two contenttypes name are Constants.CT_AV and Constants.CT_AI.

how can i resolve this?